# wordpress lock out as mail function not enabled

Tags: email, wordpress

I have my own website & domain. It has a wordpress blog. I forgot the password and basically now m locked out. It gives following mesage:

```
Possible reason: your host may have disabled the mail() function.
```

I checked on google, many people sAID to go to database and change password. I tried doing that too but still I am locked out. Can anyone help?

Comment: Perhaps the following link might help : http://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password

Comment: do you have ftp access?

Comment: Ya I do. What should I do to fix this.

Comment: Please check answer and let me know if id doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem myself by adding a new row of a user in users table and then in users _ meta table, I updated the user id to be the Id I added in users table. For example, if user id added was 2 then to give administration privileges, I updated user id 2 in user meta table. This fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

create one php file and add following code in it.

```
<?php 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require("wp-load.php");
$user = array('user_login' => 'username','user_pass' => 'password','user_email' =>   
'youremail@domain.com','role' => 'administrator');
var_dump(wp_insert_user($user));
```

change "username" and password value to something that already not have like
 username:fscore25 and password: 123456 you can change password later on and also add another email address which is working fine for you.

upload file to root of your wordpress installtion.
it should be with file named wp-load.php

then go to your browser and execute this file using
http://yourdomain.com/yourfilename.php

hope it helps

Comment: should i replace the code in wp-load.php with ur code?

Comment: no don't do it. otherwise you will loss your website.
create new file add above code and upload that new file

Comment: dint work and please be very careful while suggesting an update leading to a database breakdown

Comment: can you tell me the flow you followed? 
what is your domain? what is your file name? 
where did you uploaded? 
did you get any error on executing file? you have to login with new username password you set in file.

Comment: It seems that code I pasted has format problem. Now please copy it again and try again. in past code was missing last line. I have used above code on many sites to retrieve password.